# How to get current Transfer Rate in Commons HttpClient 3.x

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I have some code that does a bunch of HTTP GETs, POSTs, and PUTs using [Commons HttpClient 3.1](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).  I'd like to provide a current transfer speed indicator in my GUI, but was unable to find any methods for determining the transfer rate of a HttpMethod being processed.

I could easily just time the transfer and do some simple math after it was complete to determine what the speed was, but this provides a bad user experience during a long upload or download.  Does anyone know how to determine the transfer rate of a Commons HttpClient request *while* it is still being processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used HttpClient extensively, so there may be a simple hook. However, it appears that [HttpConnection.getResponseInputStream()](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnection.html#getResponseInputStream()) returns a simple `InputStream`.

To add the hook yourself, you'd need to override `HttpConnectionManager` and `HttpConnection`, to return a decorated stream that keeps track of the number of bytes read. You could then spin up a second thread to poll this stream and display the transfer rate, or (better) create the stream with a callback every N bytes (better because you don't have to care about concurrency, and you can also set N such that the callback is only invoked for large files).

Comment: Looks like I can probably combine this advice with the code from http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/dist/ch08_04.htm and make something work, I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Works.  There's no better way that I can find, unfortunately.  Good enough!

Answer (score 1):

Simpler hook would be to extend the `HttpEntityWrapper` and override the `getContent()` method:

```
public InputStream getContent() throws IOException {
    InputStream wrappedin = wrappedEntity.getContent();
    return new MyTransferRateInputStream(wrappedin);
}
```

Later you can add this as the response interceptor

```
httpClient.addResponseInterceptor(HttpResponseInterceptor itcp)
```

That way you don't need to override the mentioned `HttpConnectionManager` and `HttpConnection`